# Converting Rails 2.3 to Rails 4.0 environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that runs fine under Rails 2.3.2.
I'm trying to upgrade it to Rails 4.0, using nginx and unicorn.

My config/environment.rb has these lines that don't work:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/gems/ #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/exceptions/ )
  config.action_controller.session = { :session_key => "my_app", :secret => "c4c6eee57d9af4f2e1a9c56a49d974b7" }

  config.gem "mocha", :version => '>=0.9.4'
```

The error message I get in unicorn.log is

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
/home/art/config/environment.rb:70:in `<top (required)>'
```

and line 70 is the " Rails::Initializer.run do |config|" line above.

I guess these things have been moved out into some initializer file somewhere?
I guess bundler now handle gem versions, so I should just move the "config.gem... :version ..." lines into my Gemfile?
And where should I set session_key?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

in the new Rails require the `application.rb` file:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
```

In the `application.rb` require rails:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

usually the `session_key` is in a new initializer (under initializers folder - [look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session))

**anyway try to run `rake rails:update` it might help you change some stuff**,

or create new rails project and start to copy things from there.